# SQL Query table with order defined in adjacent table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to return distinct records from table `accounts` showing first the items having devices in status `off`.

[image]

So the result should be:

[image]

I was trying to group the records

```
SELECT account.id, account.name FROM account
  LEFT JOIN devices ON account.id = devices.account_id
  GROUP BY account.id, devices.status
  ORDER BY devices.status desc
```

but with that `account # 2` appears twice in the list as it has both `on/off` devices

Comment: Why are you even joining to `devides`?  You seem to only want values from `account`, so use `select * from account`.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: MySQL <> PostgreSQL. Please tag the specific RDBMS you are using !

Comment: @GordonLinoff He clearly states why he needs to join to `device`.  He needs to order by accounts that have at least one `device.status = off`

Comment: @mkRabbani The expected output is shown in the question...

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions!

Answer (score 1):

You can basically do conditional aggregation based sorting. Following query will do first-level sorting on whether the account has any devices off or not. All the accounts which has at-least one device `off` is considered at same level for sorting. The second level sorting is done on `account_id` (for tie-breaking).

```
SELECT account.id, account.name 
FROM account
LEFT JOIN devices ON account.id = devices.account_id
GROUP BY account.id, account.name
ORDER BY MAX(CASE devices.status WHEN 'off' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC, 
         account.id
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/49796/3)** (Thanks to *@Martin*)

---

Now, in case, you are looking to have the account have highest number of "off" devices on top, we can use the following query instead:

```
SELECT account.id, account.name 
FROM account
LEFT JOIN devices ON account.id = devices.account_id
GROUP BY account.id, account.name
ORDER BY SUM(CASE devices.status WHEN 'off' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC, 
         account.id
```

Answer (score 0):

With conditional sorting:

```
select a.* 
from account a 
order by exists (
  select 1 from devices
  where account_id = a.id and status = 'off'
) desc
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iYzS7uSNTQDgRhhtkx3c1U/0).
Results:

```
| id  | name |
| --- | ---- |
| 2   | B    |
| 1   | A    |
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query works even if you have account that has some `device` records in 'off' and some in 'on' status, it orders `device` records within same account using ROW_NUMBER() - selects one (gives priority to the one in 'off' status) and then orders such distinct account records according to whether they are 'off' or 'on':

```
select accountId, accountName
from(
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY account_id
        ORDER BY status1
    ) as rn
    , device.id
    , device.account_id
    , device.status1 as deviceStatus
    , account.id as accountId 
    , account.name as accountName
    from device
    join account on account.id = device.account_id
  ) as tableWithRowNumbers
 where rn = 1
 order by deviceStatus
```

Here is SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e04a0/19

*In my example column status is called status1.*

Answer (score 0):

If a device can have at most one "off" record (as in your example) *and* all accounts have devices, you can use:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name
FROM account a LEFT JOIN
     devices d
     ON a.id = d.account_id AND d.status = 'OFF'
ORDER BY d.status NULLS FIRST;
```

I find it curious that you would want to sort by the status but not include it in the `SELECT`.  How do you know where the status changes in the result set?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've end up using:

```
select "stores".*, "account"."country", "account"."name" as "account", "store_devices"."disconnected_num"
  from "stores" left join "accounts" as "account" on "account"."id" = "stores"."account_id"
  left join (
    SELECT store_id, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN id > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS disconnected_num
    FROM devices WHERE status = 'OFF'
    GROUP BY store_id
  ) AS store_devices
on "store_devices"."store_id" = "stores"."id"
order by "disconnected_num" asc
```